# npm install path/to/submodule failing with 128 error code

Tags: node.js, azure-devops

I have provider/gcp directroy containing its own package.json in my nodejs application.
In my root package.json, I have a script like this:

```
"installGCP": "npm i provier/gcp".
```

***I want to install provider/gcp dependencies into root node_modules folder only.***

**On my local, its working fine. But through build pipeline, its failing with error code 128.**

```
verbose stack Error: An unknown git error occurred
1173 verbose stack at makeError (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/git/lib/make-error.js:28:13)
1173 verbose stack at /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/git/lib/spawn.js:36:26
1173 verbose stack at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
1173 verbose stack at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
1174 verbose cwd /var/vsts/2/s
1175 verbose Linux 4.19.167+
1176 verbose argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "i" "provider/gcp"
1177 verbose node v16.13.0
1178 verbose npm  v8.1.0
1179 error code 128
1180 error An unknown git error occurred
1181 error command git --no-replace-objects ls-remote ssh://git@github.com/provider/gcp.git
1182 error Warning: Permanently added the ECDSA host key for IP address '140.82.112.3' to the list of known hosts.
1182 error git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
1182 error fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
1182 error
1182 error Please make sure you have the correct access rights
1182 error and the repository exists.
1183 verbose exit 128
```

I have already tried this option based on recommendation on some other forums, but it did not work either.

```
"installGCP": "git config --global url.'https://'.insteadOf git:// && npm i provider/gcp"
```

Comment: You are using an `ssh://` URL, not a `git://` URL, so `git config --global url.'https://'.insteadOf git://` has no effect. In any case, `github.com/provider/` does exist but apparently has no `gcp` repository.

Comment: @torek: but its works when we use "installGCP": "cd provider/gcp && npm i provider/gcp" instead of "installGCP": "npm i provier/gcp". How?

Comment: Finally it works with "installGCP": "npm i ./provider/gcp"